# Run batch file through Windows 7 scheduler to rename folder on network drive

Tags: windows-7, batch, nas, scheduled-tasks, rename

I'm trying to do what I believed would be very simple: have a `.bat` file that rename two folders on a network drive. The script works fine when running from prompt, but not from the scheduler. Any ideas why?

**Setup**

Network drive `\\NAS\Backup` mapped as `B:`

Folders in `Backup` that should be renamed: `Current` and `Previous`

- \\NAS\Backup\Current
- \\NAS\Backup\Previous

**Task XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.3" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2013-12-12T16:01:26.5634611</Date>
    <Author>nivis-server\nivis</Author>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <CalendarTrigger>
      <StartBoundary>2013-12-12T00:00:05</StartBoundary>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <ScheduleByWeek>
        <DaysOfWeek>
          <Saturday />
        </DaysOfWeek>
        <WeeksInterval>1</WeeksInterval>
      </ScheduleByWeek>
    </CalendarTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>nivis</UserId>
      <LogonType>Password</LogonType>
      <RunLevel>HighestAvailable</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>true</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>false</DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>
    <UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>false</UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>P3D</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>C:\script\SwitchNivisCurrent.bat</Command>
      <Arguments>&gt; execution.log</Arguments>
      <WorkingDirectory>C:\script</WorkingDirectory>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

**Script**

Located in `c:\script`

```
rename B:\Current tmp
rename B:\Previous Current
rename B:\tmp Previous
```

**========== UPDATE: Solution - courtesy of techie007 ==========**

techie007 provided the solution and the script now looks like:

```
net use x: \\10.22.0.105\nivis-nas ****PWD**** /user:nivis

x:

rename Current tmp
rename Previous Current
rename tmp Previous

net use x: /d
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple things to consider:

1. It may be executing in a user context ("nivis") that doesn't have access to that network location.
2. Drive maps are user- and session-centric.  The B: map may not exist for the user/session that the task runs in.

For 1: Ensure the user it's being run as has write/modify access to both the share and the underlying folders/files you want to change.

For 2: Modify the batch file to map B: to the network location (`net use`) at the start, and then un-map it a the end.  Alternatively, reference the network share by UNC (`\\servername\sharename`) instead of using a mapped drive.

Comment: #2 here is important.  A good example of this would be mapping a drive in Explorer, and then starting an admin command prompt - note that the drive mappings do not exist in that context.

Comment: I tried your second proposal and it worked. Thanks!